# how to ignore error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a sticky application and i cant use IP spoofing or things like that. So I get No HTTP response code error in the long run.

I want jmeter to ignore this error particular error but be capable of calculating other HTTP error such as 429 Too Many Requests , 404 Not Found, 5xx errors and so on and on. However how to make jmeter able to just ignore one particular error.

The following is my error i am getting, I need a way so that jmeter ignores this error but carries on calculating other types of error.

Pic:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need it, maybe you just need to follow steps from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page, but here you go:

1. Add [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Listener's "Script" area:

   ```
   if (sampleResult.getResponseMessage().equals("Non HTTP response message: Connection reset")) {
       sampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
   }
   ```

`sampleResult` is a shorthand to [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) class instance which provides extended read/write access to all appropriate methods and fields.

See JavaDoc for more information and [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive guide on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements in your JMeter test

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I love your contribution in blazemeter. I read a lot of articles you have written about performance testing and jmeter.. Thanks